# Structures between files

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I'm getting an error every time I try to compile. It's probably something stupid, but I can't figure it out. This is the error:
aldrbw01@timber:~/project5$ make

gcc -g -c crawler.c -o crawler.o

crawler.c: In function ‘crawler’:

crawler.c:12: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token

make: *** [crawler.o] Error 1

```
#include "crawler.h"
#include "indexPage.h"
//My Carwler

int checkIndex(char* url, char** urlArray, const int MAX_N);
int getLink(const char* srcAddr, char* link, const int maxLinkLength);
char** missionControl(const char* FILE_NAME, const int Max_N);


char** crawler(const char* FILE_NAME, const int Max_N){
char** URLs;
queryHelper **structArray = malloc(sizeof(struct *wordControl)*50); 
URLs= missionControl(FILE_NAME, Max_N); 
return URLs;
}


char** missionControl(const char* FILE_NAME, const int Max_N){ 

const int  MAX_BUFFER = 1000;
    int cursor = 0;
    int x;
     char** urlArray = malloc(sizeof(char*)*Max_N);

    for(x=0; x<Max_N; x++) {
        urlArray[x] = NULL;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    char* url;
    url = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    int* hoplimit;
    hoplimit = malloc(sizeof(int));
    char* reader;
    reader = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    int numHops;
    while(fgets(reader,MAX_BUFFER ,file ) !=NULL && cursor<Max_N) {
    sscanf(reader, "%s %d", url, hoplimit);
        numHops=0;
        while (1) {
            if (checkIndex(url, urlArray, Max_N)) {
                                indexMyStuff(url);
                cursor++;
            }
             numHops++;
            if(numHops<=*hoplimit && cursor<Max_N) {

                if (!getLink(url,url,MAX_BUFFER)) {
                    break;
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    free(url);
    free(hoplimit);
    free(reader);
    fclose(file);
    return urlArray;
   }




     //--------------------Header FILE for IndexPage------------------------//
     #ifndef INDEX_H
     #define INDEX_H
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <ctype.h>

     struct wordControl{
       char** words;
      int* countArry;
     };
     typedef struct wordControl queryHelper;
     queryHelper *indexMyStuff(char* argv);
     #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect syntax for obtaining the size of a pointer to a `struct`:

```
sizeof(struct *wordControl)
//            ^
// There should be no asterisk between struct keyword and the tag
```

The asterisk goes after the type name, not between the `struct` and the tag:

```
sizeof(struct wordControl*)
```